# Blender Asset Browser - assign assets to different catalog without opening each .blend file

Tags: asset-browser

Is it possible to assign assets to a different catalog without opening their respective
.blend file? As far as I understood, you can only assign an asset to a catalog by opening the .blend file in which the asset is saved in. This seems quite impractical for managing large asset libraries. Say I would like to create the sub-catalog "tables" of an existing catalog "furniture" some time in the future because my library grew larger. It would seem logical to select the assets in the asset browser and drop them into a newly created catalog (like in a file browser) rather than opening each file. I don't understand why it's not working like that in the first place, but maybe someone knows a workaround?